# Is this JSON data, XML, or something else?

Tags: validation

I am trying to use Python to parse this data, but I have no idea what kind of data this is. It was found from a div tag that had "data-bind" as an attribute.

```
component: {
name: 'product-detail',
params: {
    hasVariants: true,
    name: 'HORSESHOE ARM CHAIR',
    hasCategory: true,
    superCategoryName: 'Furniture',
    categoryDisplayName: 'Living Room',
    categorySlug: 'living-room',
    subcategoryDisplayName: 'Chairs',
    subcategorySlug: 'chairs',
    collection: {
        id: 1045,
        name: 'Van Thiel &amp; Co.',
        description: 'Authentic European antiques are reproduced by seasoned artisans to capture the look of Old World craftsmanship. Every delicious detail - carving or ironwork to painting or patina - is done by hand.',
        isFeatured: true,
        isNew: false,
        image: '/FourHandsMarketplace/media/General/Featured%20Collections/VANTHIEL.jpg?width=500',
        shortDescription: 'Capture the grandness of authentic European antiques, reproduced by seasoned artisans and finished by hand to echo the romantic patina of Old World craftsmanship.\r\n',
        uri: '/collections/van-thiel-co'
    },
    attributes: [{
        id: 559,
        name: 'COVER',
        displayOrder: 30,
        swatches: true,
        values: [{
            id: 13622,
            name: 'SCARECROW BARN',
            displayOrder: 1,
            swatchUrl: '/s3/fhphotos/Y C6517-V6_PRM_1.jpg?width=200&amp;height=200&amp;mode=crop'
        }]       
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's related to KnockoutJS component Bindings, see following link:

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-custom-elements.html